# Handling Multiple Polygon Object

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Am trying to add/remove multiple polygon on the google map. On clicking each polygon, I have to show some info window for the corresponding polygon. On clicking the polygon, I couldn't maintain the polygon object.

Sample code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < multipleFlights.length; i++) 
{
    google.maps.event.addListener(multipleFlights[i], 'click', arrayfn); // $(multipleFlights[i]).click(function () { alert('x'); });
}
```

How can I get the current polygon object in the `arrayfn` function .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, there are at least two solutions:

- function closure (with a function like createClickablePoly() to associate the InfoWindow contents with the Polygon) - [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_clickable_squares.html)
- member variable containing the InfoWindow content accessed by the click listener function.