# Unable to get bounds of drawing rectangle on map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/g97922w8/1/). Why am I getting this error:

> overlay.getBounds is not a function

while trying to get bounds of drawn rectangle on the map?

```js
var rectangle;
var map;
var drawingManager;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 44.5452,
      lng: -78.5389
    },
    zoom: 9
  });
  drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager();
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(overlay) {
    rectangle = overlay;
    drawingManager.setOptions({
      drawingMode: null,
      drawingControl: false
    });
    
     var bounds = overlay.getBounds();
     var start = bounds.getNorthEast();
     var end = bounds.getSouthWest();
     console.log( start);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);


function drawRec() {
  //Setting options for the Drawing Tool. In our case, enabling Polygon shape.
  if (!!rectangle && !!rectangle.overlay && !!rectangle.overlay.setMap) {
    rectangle.overlay.setMap(null);
  }
  drawingManager.setOptions({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
    drawingControl: false,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE]
    },
    rectangleOptions: {
      strokeColor: '#6c6c6c',
      strokeWeight: 3.5,
      fillColor: '#926239',
      fillOpacity: 0.6,
      editable: true,
      draggable: true
    }

  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);

}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="drawRec();">Draw Rectangle</button>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error: "overlay.getBounds is not a function", because `overlay.getBounds()` is not a function.  `overlay` is not a `google.maps.Rectangle`, but it has an `overlay` property which is.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(overlay) {
  rectangle = overlay;
  drawingManager.setOptions({
    drawingMode: null,
    drawingControl: false
  });
  var bounds = overlay.overlay.getBounds();
  var start = bounds.getNorthEast();
  var end = bounds.getSouthWest();

  console.log(start.toUrlValue(6));
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/g97922w8/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var rectangle;
var map;
var drawingManager;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 44.5452,
      lng: -78.5389
    },
    zoom: 9
  });
  drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager();
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(overlay) {
    rectangle = overlay;
    drawingManager.setOptions({
      drawingMode: null,
      drawingControl: false
    });
    var bounds = overlay.overlay.getBounds();
    var start = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var end = bounds.getSouthWest();

    console.log(bounds.toUrlValue(6));
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);


function drawRec() {
  //Setting options for the Drawing Tool. In our case, enabling Polygon shape.
  if (!!rectangle && !!rectangle.overlay && !!rectangle.overlay.setMap) {
    rectangle.overlay.setMap(null);
  }
  drawingManager.setOptions({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
    drawingControl: false,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE]
    },
    rectangleOptions: {
      strokeColor: '#6c6c6c',
      strokeWeight: 3.5,
      fillColor: '#926239',
      fillOpacity: 0.6,
      editable: true,
      draggable: true
    }

  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);

}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="drawRec();">Draw Rectangle</button>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks geocodezip is there any way we assign a Info Windows to the rectangle, as well?

Comment: Yes, there is.  That is another question, as there is no information in this one to put in the infowindow.

Comment: from a quick search: [GoogleMaps API: Rectangle and InfoWindow coupling issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171285/googlemaps-api-rectangle-and-infowindow-coupling-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer#drawing_events

The `overlay` event in your event listener has two properties:

- overlay
- type

So you'd need to change your code to something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(overlayEvent) {
    rectangle = overlayEvent.overlay;
    drawingManager.setOptions({
      drawingMode: null,
      drawingControl: false
    });

     var bounds = rectangle.getBounds();
     var start = bounds.getNorthEast();
     var end = bounds.getSouthWest();
});
```